# Laradock Error: The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 15, which is not compatible with this version 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1)

Tags: postgresql, laradock

I installed laradock + postgres and facing error

```
[1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
[1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 15, which is not compatible with this version 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1).
```

What I must todo?

file .env

```
### POSTGRES ##############################################

POSTGRES_VERSION=latest
POSTGRES_CLIENT_VERSION=latest
POSTGRES_DB=default
POSTGRES_USER=default
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB=./postgres/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Dockerfile - postgres

```
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=latest
FROM postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}

CMD ["postgres"]

EXPOSE 5432
```

Comment: You must either run PostgreSQL v15 or create a v16 data directory using `initdb`.